# How to send the password automatically in gpg's symmetric encryption?

Tags: gnupg

I want to make a symmetric encryption  for the file `/tmp/public.txt`.
To do this I can use gpg as following:

```
gpg --symmetric /tmp/public.txt
```

The command will invoke the `enter passphrase` window, but I would like to send the password  automatically.

[image]

I have tried with:

```
echo "mylongpasswordhere"  | gpg --passphrase-fd 0   --symmetric /tmp/public.txt
```

but the **Enter passphrase** window  still  pop up.

How to send the password  automatically in  gpg's symmetric encryption?

Comment: Please refer to [gpg-ask-for-password-even-with-passphrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your GnuPG version (>= 2.1.0 ) you need to add "--pinentry-mode loopback" to the command.

For GnuPG version >= 2.1.0 but < 2.1.12 you also need to add: "allow-loopback-pinentry" to the ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

Your command would then be:

```
echo "mylongpasswordhere"  | gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-fd 0   --symmetric /tmp/public.txt
```

Alternatively you don't have to use passphrase-fd and the echo but can directly provide the passphrase:

```
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase "somepass" --symmetric /tmp/public.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I stumbled on this question having the same problem, I'll post the answer that actually helped me (from other SE question). The key options here are `--batch --yes`:

```
$ gpg --passphrase hunter2 --batch --yes --symmetric file_to_enc
```

(Taken from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase) )

That way you can actually encrypt a file symmetrically supplying the key as commandline argument, although this might mean that other users of the system might see the passphrase used.

Answer (score 0):

```
key="it is a long password to encrypt and decrypt my file in symmetric encryption
"
```

Encypt public.txt.

```
openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in public.txt -k ${key} -out public.asc
```

Decrypt  public.asc.

```
openssl enc -d -des3 -a -salt -k ${key} -in public.asc -out public.out
```

Can i draw a conclusion that openssl is a more powerful tool for encryption than gpg?